Why did we use the REPLACE operator while inserting values in the Member (junction) table?
I am currently doing a Coursera course (Using Databases with Python) on Python 3. In an assignment of making a roster which shows which user is doing what course, given to make a many-to-many relationship among database in SQL, I can not understand why we have to use the REPLACE operator in the Member (junction) table.
The sample code is given below:
(I thought like before, I have to use the OR IGNORE clause.)
import json
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('rosterdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Do some setup
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Member;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Course;

CREATE TABLE User (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title  TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Member (
    user_id     INTEGER,
    course_id   INTEGER,
    role        INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, course_id)
)
''')

fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = 'roster_data.json'

#   [ "Charley", "si110", 1 ],
#   [ "Mea", "si110", 0 ],

str_data = open(fname).read()
json_data = json.loads(str_data)

for entry in json_data:

    name = entry[0]
    title = entry[1]
    role = entry[2]


    print((name, title))

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO User (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( name, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = ? ', (name, ))
    user_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Course (title)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( title, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Course WHERE title = ? ', (title, ))
    course_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Member
        (user_id, course_id, role) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )''',
        ( user_id, course_id, role ) )

    conn.commit()


How should we know when/why you want to replace something and when not? Check your requirements, that's nothing we can do for you.

the INSERT OR REPLACE statement does not generate an error if a row already exists.

INSERT OR REPLACE means that if the primary key already exists in the table, the row will be updated with the specified values. So if there are multiple elements in the JSON with the same name and title, the first one will create a new row in Member, and later ones will replace the role.
If you don't use OR REPLACE, you'll get an error if there are duplicate elements.
You could instead use OR IGNORE, as you do for the name and title. Then these duplicates will be skipped without an error.
So the difference between using IGNORE or REPLACE is whether you want to use the first or last role when there are duplicate name+title combinations. If there shouldn't be duplicates in the first place, you probably shouldn't use either option when inserting into Member.
